# Radiobutton-like behaving Vue.js components

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js

I have the following Vue.js components, which basically are supposed to have a radiobutton-like behaviour:

```
// Parent Component
<template>
  <child-component
    v-for="element in elements"
  </child-component>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from './Child.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  props: {
    elements: Array
  },
  methods: {
    activate(e) {
      for (let i of this.$children) {
        i.active = false;
      }

      if (e < this.$children.length) {
        this.$children[e].active = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and

```
// Child Component
<template>
  {{active}}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    active: Boolean
  }
}
</script>
```

This works fine but only the parent can decide to activate one of the children (and thus deactivate all others).

I want however also be able to **allow each child to activate itself** (and by a magic property of its parent, deactivate all other siblings).

Obviously I do not want each child to know about its siblings and mess with their `.active` prop (super bad design).

I would rather not have a children communicate back up to the parent and call some method (still bad design as I could only reuse the child components in parents that have `activate()` method).

Instead I would like the parent to listen to changes to all children `active` props and take action when one of them changes. That way the parent entirely encapsulates the radio button behavior.

How can this interaction be implemented in Vue.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at two-way binding: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop_Binding_Types

This allows you to sync a property's value in both directions, meaning the parent or the child has access to change the variable.  Then you can watch for changes on the parent and update accordingly.

I think a better option would be to create a RadioSet component, which then would house a number of radio buttons.  This would eliminate your concern about a parent having to have the `activate()` method.  You could simply pass in an object with a series of `id` and `values` that could be used to generate the buttons.